# How to check if Intel RealSense device is ready after hardware reset?

Tags: c++, realsense

After calling

```
dev.hardware_reset();
```

How do I know if the device is ready before starting the pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

`void rs2::context::set_devices_changed_callback (T callback)`      [check doc](https://intelrealsense.github.io/librealsense/doxygen/classrs2_1_1context.html#a04a26a20a476810edab3b549f29089fc)

you can set a callback using `set_devices_changed_callback` to get notified when the device is connected or disconnected. Inside the callback you can use `query_devices` to know find the available devices. if the device is available you can start reading the frames.

Answer (score 0):

My code to do that :

```
qDebug() << "[Stream] --- --- RealSense camera hardware reset...";
rs2::context ctx;
rs2::device dev = ctx.query_devices().front(); // Reset the first device
uint32_t nbDevices = ctx.query_devices().size();
qDebug() << "[Stream] --- --- RealSense camera hardware reset... nb devices :" << nbDevices;
dev.hardware_reset();
rs2::device_hub hub(ctx);
dev = hub.wait_for_device(); // waiting
qDebug() << "[Stream] --- --- RealSense camera hardware reset... OK";
```